# Adding Google Analytics Script Into Website

Tags: php, google-analytics

I was given a script for adding google analytics into my website, but all the pages in my website are .php pages. I tried just inserting the script at the end of the index.php but so far it doesn't seem to be working. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Google analytics is JavaScript code, so you will have to put the code in between a <script> tag

Comment: @zerk's snark is quite harsh, but this question is impossible to answer. You need to put the script in all of your pages, period. We have no idea what your pages look like and you're not giving any hint, so we can't help you.

Comment: include it within your <header> section and make sure you paste it BEFORE the </header>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Analytics code should be in the `<head>` of your documents just before the closing `</head>` tag. If you're using PHP includes or some kind of templating system you need to find the file that has that code and place it in there.

Keep in mind that it takes 24 hours for the results to show up in your analytics report.

Comment: I will try using a ctrl+f, thank you a lot for the help

Comment: Sadly there are no head or body tags in the index.php file

Comment: It will be in a separate file. Possibly called `header.php`.

Comment: Other people are telling me to use the footer, I found the header and footer php files, which should I use? :)

Comment: That is obsolete advice. It belongs in the header. It used to go in the footer but now that the code is asynchronous it should be in the header for more accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `<footer></footer>` tags on every page. Put it between those. You can do it like this:

```
<footer>
OTHER STUFF IN YOUR FOOTER
OTHER STUFF IN YOUR FOOTER
OTHER STUFF IN YOUR FOOTER
OTHER STUFF IN YOUR FOOTER



<script type="text/javascript">


 Google analytics code here


</script>
</footer>
```

Comment: I will have to search for those tags, are they in .php files too?

Comment: are you using a shopping cart or writing your own pages?